# Qt quick controls - where is defined ScrollView orientation?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

i created my custom style for ScrollView, but actually i don't know how to check what orientation of scroll is it (horizontal or vertical? I need use different image for each of them).

[source code of scrollview style](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/a37fdb9d72567cabf4bd0fac0cfd15ab3cefed3e%3asrc/styles/ScrollViewStyle.qml#L108)

In this source code, that i found, is used word `horizontal`, but where it comes from? I don't see any declaration of `horizontal` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from [this line](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/a37fdb9d72567cabf4bd0fac0cfd15ab3cefed3e%3asrc/styles/ScrollViewStyle.qml#L288). In newer versions of Qt, properties for style components are exposed through the `styleData` object; this is now standard practice for all Qt Quick Controls styling. In the case of `ScrollViewStyle`, commit [e0c8035c](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/commit/e0c8035c3db5c3c68602a90a5addbb2d48c0733f)  updated the code to use `styleData` instead.